# Is there a free site to play Yu-Gi-Oh?

Tags: online, yu-gi-oh

Anything fairly priced will also work. Any suggestions?

Comment: There's an app that is suitable: Yugioh Duel generation. NOTE that it's an APP

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://www.duelingnetwork.com/

I used to hit problems with the intro and needed to block the music file they use (it's not a part of the flash file for some weird reason), but it works well for what it does.

Comment: This site is no longer active it has been removed for legal reasons

Comment: http://www.duelingbook.com/ is a very similar replacement.

Answer (score 3):

I really enjoy using : http://ygopro.org/

Its really well made and constantly updating

Answer (score 2):

DevPro is also really good. It's actually better since it emulates the rules for you. Can't link unfortunately, but it should be fairly easy to find.

Answer (score 1):

https://duelingnexus.com/
This site is free to use (for a limited time) and you can make your own deck to play online with other people